# Address individual content scripts in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

if you have an extension with multiple content scripts injected into a single page, is it possible to address a specific content script on the page rather than broadcasting to all content scripts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could execute your content scripts in your `background.js` instead of defining it in your `manifest.json`:

```
if (condition) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'contentscript1.js' });
} else {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'contentscript2.js' });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I meant this more as is there a way to send a message to a specific content script out of a bunch of content scripts already running on a page, not so much as to run certain content scripts at certain times.

Comment: This depends on your logic in your content script. All content scripts receive a message if you send it to them. You have to specify what to do with this message by your logic in there. Those content scripts can  communicate with each other, e.g. by global variables or events.

Comment: So there is no way to directly message a specific script running, so the message is broadcast to all listening scripts correct? I know you can filter messages, I'm more interested in seeing if you can address running content scripts.

Comment: You have to see that they are concatenated internally. Just like the scripts in your browser. It gives one huge script at the end, they aren't really separated. (That's why you can share variables between them)